# GUI not updated from another thread when using PyGtk

Tags: python, multithreading, pygtk

I am using PyGTK to build a GUI application. I want to update the textview widget from another thread but the widget is not getting updated everytime i try an update. What should i do to get a reliable GUI updating?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

GTK+ is not thread-safe, so you should not simply call GUI update methods from other threads. [glib.idle_add](http://pygtk.org/docs/pygobject/glib-functions.html#function-glib--idle-add) (or gobject.idle_add in older PyGTK versions) can be used for this purpose.

Instead of writing:

```
label.set_text("foo")
```

you would write:

```
glib.idle_add(label.set_text, "foo")
```

which causes the function call to be queued in GTK+.

If you need to run multiple statements, it's often easier to wrap them in a function:

```
def idle():
    label1.set_text("foo")
    label2.set_text("bar")
glib.idle_add(idle)
```

Make sure that the function passed to `idle_add` does not return `True`; otherwise it will be queued again.

**Edit:** As Daniel pointed out, you need to call `gtk.gdk.threads_init()` anywhere in your program first.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the previous answers, GTK is not "thread safe," but it is "thread-aware" - see this page on Threads: [https://developer.gnome.org/gdk2/stable/gdk2-Threads.html](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gdk/unstable/gdk-Threads.html)

In order to modify GTK widgets from another thread you have to use GTK's locking. Call `gtk.threads_init()` immediately after importing the gtk module, and then you can update like so:

```
gtk.threads_enter()
# make changes...
gtk.threads_leave()
```

Note that the above will not work on Windows (see the link above). On Windows you must use `gobject.idle_add()` as explained above, though don't forget to put `gobject.threads_init()` directly after importing gobject in your code! The idle_add() function will execute the update itself in the main thread (the thread running gtk.main()).

Comment: Good point. Another good write-up regarding these two approaches can be seen in a PyGTK FAQ entry: http://faq.pygtk.org/index.py?file=faq20.006.htp&req=show

Answer (score -1):

the same may be achieved using gobject.idle_add method whose syntax is same as above,you have to import the module gobject

Answer (score -1):

What Johannes said is correct, however since GTK is a wrapper for the glib and gobject things, you would actually want to use gtk.idle_add(). No need for the unnecessary imports.